# Wordpress update_user_meta onclick with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm attempting to update_user_meta via Ajax call in Wordpress.
I keep getting a 'success!' console log, but no data is returned and the user meta field is not being updated.

general.js on a button click:

```
var newViewPreference = jQuery(this).attr('id');
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            'action':'update_view_pref',
            'viewPref' : newViewPreference
        },
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("success!");
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log("fail");
        }
});
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_view_pref', 'update_view_pref');
function update_view_pref() {
    if(empty($_POST) || !isset($_POST)) {
        ajaxStatus('error', 'Nothing to update.');
    } else {
        try {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $viewPref = $_POST['viewPref'];
            if ($viewPref == 'toggle-grid') {
                update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpcf-shop-view-preference', 'grid' );
            } elseif ($viewPref == 'toggle-list') {
                update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpcf-shop-view-preference', 'list' );
            }
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone able to pinpoint where I'm going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: seems fine, did you try and echo out your user id to makesure it exists? Also you have 2 ifs but no else - check the $viewPref variable.

Comment: @David i changed $_POST to $_REQUEST and voila!

Comment: @Tuesdave Hey Dave, I know this is an old post - but I'm trying to acheive something similar whereby I send info to wp_usermeta via ajax on the click of a button. My button idetifier is '.skizzar_onboarding #next.step5' - when this is clicked I want to send 'dashboard' using update_user_meta where the key is 'onboarding_status' - how can I acheieve this by modifying your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing $_POST to $_REQUEST worked.

Can anyone explain why $_POST didn't work but $_REQUEST did?

I was submitting the data to the ajax request via a button click (not a form).

Comment: just because you didn't use `type: "POST"` in your ajax call.